# Rails 3 app not pulling db from heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Any help would be nice. The heroku logs don't say anythinga bout this. I'm able to push the app onto heroku fine. Usually I am able to pull the database from heroku by just doing heroku db:pull --confirm appname. Now, when I pull or even push I just get this error. 
 ! not authorized.

Comment: I have the same problem!! I seems to be a heroku problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you logged in with the Heroku Toolbelt?
Try `heroku login` first.

Comment: yup I'm logged in with Heroku Toolbelt.

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue with the API at the moment, should be patched soon: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/509

**UPDATE:** should be fixed now

Comment: oh my! you saved me a lot of trouble. I should definitely keep track of statuses on heroku. Thanks!

Comment: Try again now, should be fixed

Answer (score 0):

I is a Heroku problem.
Check the status here https://status.heroku.com/incidents/509